# I am getting Bad Request 400 when I try to access /users endpoint on Google OAuth 2.0 Playground

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, oauth2-playground

this is my first time I am using Google OAuth 2.0 Playground. I logged in using my personal @gmail.com account, under Admin SDK API directory_v1 I have selected this scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly, but I am not able to get the info that I need.

Possible operations for this scope includes listing users using this endpoint `https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users`. But when I make request to the endpoint I am getting this error

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Bad Request", 
    "code": 400, 
    "errors": [
      {
        "reason": "badRequest", 
        "message": "Bad Request", 
        "domain": "global"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am also using this endpoint `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo` to get user info, then get the user id(Which is the id field in the response), then use the id in this endpoint `https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/{userKey}`, but I am getting this response.

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Resource Not Found: userKey", 
    "code": 404, 
    "errors": [
      {
        "reason": "notFound", 
        "message": "Resource Not Found: userKey", 
        "domain": "global"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried this using the default OAuth 2.0 credentials and also using my own OAuth credentials
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what method are you calling userinfo endpoint requires an Access token with profile or openid scope

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo the user info endpoint `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo` works well and I am getting the response. What is not working is this endpoint `https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/{userKey}`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. For this API `https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users`, I needed to add a domain. So it should be `https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?domain=sampled.com` and also you need to ensure you have the ADMIN RIGHTS.

On the other endpoint `https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/{userKey}` it failed since I didn't have the ADMIN RIGHTS.